# Postgresql Functions UNKOWN parameter

Tags: function, postgresql

this is my table

```
CREATE TABLE pago
(
  codigo serial NOT NULL,
  codigocaja integer NOT NULL,
  codigotarjeta integer,
  codigocheque integer,
  formapago character varying(1) NOT NULL,
  tipocomp character varying(1) NOT NULL,
  importetotal money NOT NULL,
  fecha date NOT NULL,
  codigoalumno integer NOT NULL,
  codigodeposito integer,
  vigencia boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
  descripcion character varying(200),
  CONSTRAINT "PK_CodigoPago" PRIMARY KEY (codigo),
  CONSTRAINT "FK_CodigoAlumno" FOREIGN KEY (codigoalumno)
      REFERENCES alumno (codigoalumno) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT "FK_CodigoCaja" FOREIGN KEY (codigocaja)
      REFERENCES caja (codigo) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT "FK_CodigoCheque" FOREIGN KEY (codigocheque)
      REFERENCES cheque (codigo) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT "FK_CodigoDeposito" FOREIGN KEY (codigodeposito)
      REFERENCES deposito (codigo) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT "FK_CodigoTarjeta" FOREIGN KEY (codigotarjeta)
      REFERENCES tarjeta (codigo) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT "UN_CodigoPago" UNIQUE (codigo)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE pago
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

and this is my function for adding a new row

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_inspagar(vcodcaja integer, vcodtarjeta integer, vcodcheque integer,  vformapago character varying, vtipocomp character varying,vimporte money ,vfecha date, vcodal integer, vcoddeposito integer,vdesc character varying)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
begin

INSERT INTO pago(codigocaja,codigotarjeta,codigocheque,formapago,tipocomp,importetotal,fecha,codigoalumno,codigodeposito,descripcion)
VALUES (vcodcaja,vcodtarjeta,vcodcheque,vformapago,vtipocomp,vimporte,vfecha,vcodal,vcoddeposito,vdesc);

end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

and when i execute the functions like this

```
select * from fn_inspagar(1,2,null,'T','B',200,'2013-01-01',196,0,'matricula')
```

as a result i have the following

ERROR:  no existe la función fn_inspagar(integer, integer, integer, unknown, unknown, integer, unknown, integer, integer, unknown)

Comment: I think you've missed the actual problem off the end of your question...

Comment: Sorry! it is update now!

Comment: `fn_inspagar()` vs `fn_inspago()`. (looks like a typo)

Comment: I would stay away from the `money` datatype. Use `decimal` instead. That will cause much fewer trouble in the long run.

Comment: Let me just echo @a_horse_with_no_name; I found the money datatype to be much more trouble than it was worth, especially for a multi-currency application. Decimal with an implied decimal place (4 or 6) worked better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the money type is not a 'trivial conversion', you need to cast the 200 value in your example as `money` when calling the function (otherwise PostgreSQL gives the priority to an integer conversion).

Working example:

```
select * from fn_inspagar(1,2, null, 'T', 'B',CAST ( 200 as money) , '2013-01-01' ,196,0, 'matricula')
```

Have a look here to get more informations on how PostgreSQL handles the signature of functions:

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/typeconv-func.html

Comment: Linking to [version 8.1 is really off target](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). [I fixed it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108714/best-way-to-reference-the-postgresql-manual).

Comment: @MitoCode: Bear in mind that many credible sources will suggest avoiding the `CURRENCY` datatype altogether and advocate the use of `NUMERIC(p, s)` instead.